# How can I check if WinActivate succeeded?

Tags: autohotkey

I have a troublesome application which sometimes fails to activate when using [WinActivate](https://autohotkey.com/docs/commands/WinActivate.htm). This typically happens if there's an open dialogue prompt or popup window.

To prevent accidental input errors, I want to verify whether the window has been activated. Ideally, I would like to throw an error if WinActivate fails, such as in the following pseudocode:

```
If !WinActivate, Calculator  ; pseudo code
   MsgBox 'Calculator' not found. Stopping script...
   Exit, 1
}
```

As far as I can tell WinActive doesn't return any values, which means I am unable to directly check whether it succeeded

**How can I check if WinActivate succeeded?**

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**This attempts to activate a window and complains if it hasn't succeeded within 2 seconds**

```
WinActivate windowTitle
WinWaitActive windowTitle, , 2
if ErrorLevel
{
  MsgBox 'windowTitle' not found. Stopping script...
  Exit  1
}
```

**Same code wrapped in a generic function**

```
F2::activate( "Untitled - Notepad" )

activate(title)
{
  WinActivate %title%
  WinWaitActive %title%, , 2
  if ErrorLevel
  {
    MsgBox '%title%' not found. Stopping script...
    Exit  1
  }
}
```